# HOW TO CHANGE ALIAS ON CMD DIRECTORY

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

So i just accidentally did someething to my cmd, that look something like this.[CLICK HERE TO SEE THE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvJ3m.png)

i wonder how do i reset it back to default state, where the name is will be like C:/User/MyUser or something.
please i seriously need help thanks. because i forgot how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have changed your prompt to `lol`. To revert to standard you can type

```
prompt [$M$p]
```

To get a list of possible settings please type

```
help prompt
```

To make your preferred setting persistent you have to press `<Windows><Pause>` on the keyboard, navigate to 'advanced system settings', and press button 'environment variables'. There look for the variable 'prompt' and set the value to [$M$p].

Comment: `[$M$p]` is not the default (it's `$P$G`). To revert back to the default, just type `prompt` (without any parameters)

Comment: thank you very much , im glad that y'all help me